# Reach Local Proxy Page - Duplicate content?

Tags: duplicate-content, canonical-url

We have a client who has instructed Reach Local to manage their paid SEO work etc.  RL have created a proxy version of the page at http://example-px.rtrk.co.uk which mirrors the existing site completely.

Would I be correct in assuming that this would count as duplicate content and one or both of the sites would be penalized because of this?  And would the addition of a rel="canonical" meta-tag on the proxy site assist with this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they would be penalized. Yes a canonical meta tag would help. However Reach Local have put a [robots.txt](http://example-px.rtrk.co.uk/robots.txt) file there to stop search engines crawling it.